# WWW::Selenium does not work as a normal browser

Tags: perl, selenium, checkbox, automation

I am using `WWW::Selenium` to automate a webflow.
When I check a checkbox (Select all), all the checkboxes present in the page gets checked and a link becomes active.

But when I do it using `WWW::Seleium::check()`, the checkbox is getting checked, but all other checkboxes and the link have no effect.

Can someone please give some pointer as to what is the issue?

**CODE**

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use WWW::Selenium;
my $sel = WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost",
                              port => 5555,
                              browser => "*iexplore",
                              browser_url => "http://mygengo.com/string/p/demoproject-1/edit/slave/ui/de_de",
                            );

$sel->start;
$sel->open("http://mygengo.com/string/p/demoproject-1/edit/slave/ui/de_de");
$cook = $sel->get_cookie();

$sel->type("login_email", 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$sel->type("login_password", "xxxxxxxxx");
$sel->click("Submit");
$sel->wait_for_page_to_load(9000);
$sel->open("http://mygengo.com/string/p/demoproject-1/edit/slave/ui/de_de");

$sel->check('id=select-all-visible'); #ISSUE: This just checks the checkbox, but has no effect on other checkboxes & links, like it happens when done on the browser
$sel->click('id=show-order-translation');
$sel->wait_for_page_to_load(9000);
```

Comment: The question is too vague. Which Web page? Show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using `WWW::Selenium::click()` instead of `WWW::Selenium::check()`.

If checking the checkbox results in some page actions, go for `click` instead of `check`.